# Chrome not responding to CSS

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm having hard time getting a select field to work as I would like to in the latest version of Chrome.
It all works perfectly in Firefox but Chrome is just being stubborn.
How it should be in Chrome:

[image]

How it actually is in Chrome:

[image]

HTML:

```
<td><!--<input type='text' name='ruum' />-->
<select>
    <option type="text" value="ruum">Uks</option>
    <option type="text" value="ruum">Kaks</option>
    <option type="text" value="ruum">Kolm</option>
</select>
</td>
```

CSS:

```
option{ /*works for firefox but not for chrome*/
width:8.5em;
float:left;
}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { /*doesn't do anything*/
 option{
    width:8.5em;
    float:left;
 } 
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Set the width on the `select`, not on the `option`:

```
select {
    width: 8.5em;
    float: left;
}
```

Also, `option` doesn't have a `type` attribute. See: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-option-element

Answer (score 1):

Set the size of the `<select>`, not the `<option>`:

```
select{
    width:8.5em;
    float:left;
}
```

See this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BDhxb/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try applying the styles to `select` instead of `option`.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tttp2/